# Convert a string date to another date format

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I have a date from a server in format `01/01/2012 12:00:00PM` and I want to convert that date to `ISO8601 format` but I keep getting a `Parse Exception` when I try to parse the date

my code

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ");
Date timestamp = null;
try{
    timestamp = format.parse(startDate);

    startDate = format.format(timestamp);
}catch(ParseException e){

}
```

Comment: If you're working alot with dates, have a look at Joda DateTime, is use it everywhere; makes stuff easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First parse your String and create Date object with incoming format.

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
```

Then create another date format with the format you are looking for and format the date object.

```
DateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ");

 startDate = format2.format(timestamp);
```